# How can I transfer this code (originally for FPS template) for use in a Third Person Template?

Tags: unreal, first-person-shooter, blueprints, third-person-view

I learned how to create a blueprint for making a character be able to pick up and drop objects:
[image: code]
It did not work, and I believe the reason is because it was originally made to work for the FPS template that Unreal comes with.  I decided to use the Third Person template, and I think that's why it's not working.
Am I correct?  What blueprint coding should I be looking at?  What's missing, or what's preventing this from working?
Thanks!

Comment: What specific symptoms of "not working" do you observe? This can be important to narrowing down the problem and solution.

Comment: well, when I try to pick up a physics object, a red dot acting as a ray will appear where I pressed the key that activate the pick up action.

Comment: And you want that red dot to not appear? Try to err on the side of explaining too much.

Comment: ok.  I have no idea what that red dot is.  I just followed a tutorial to come up with the code that I showed.  It should make it so I can pick up and drop physics objects.  But it doesn't.  The person who made it started with the 3ps template, and I started with the fps.  So I'm guessing that there was something important in the fps template that is necessary for this code to work.

Comment: I figured it out!  was a wrong node!  Thanks for the help, man!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the problem was that I had put a divide node where I should have put a vector add node.
[image: solution]

Once I fixed this, it worked fine!